# Binding a list to a single input field - spring boot , thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to have a tag system in my application, where multiple tags can be assigned by entering input into a single field. Similar to what we have here at SO.

I have an `Article` class that has `Set<ArticleTag> articleTags` as an attribute.

The only way I could think of doing this is with `@RequestParam` and then split the `String` in `Spring boot` app. I am wondering, is there a way I can put the existing values in a custom field?

So far I have got the `HTML` snippet below.

```
            <div th:each="tag,i: ${article.articleTags}">
                <input type="text" th:value="*{articleTags[__${i.index}__].tagName}" />
            </div>
```

This produces the following view:

[image: Tags]

> Edit 1

Worth probably mention that I have two attributes in the `ArticleTag` class -  `ID` and `tagName`. If I do a `<input type="text" th:value="${article.articleTags}"/>`, this produces a list of `ID` values not `tagName`, which is what I am after.

> Edit 2

```
<input th:each="arg: ${article.articleTags.value}" th:value="${arg.tagName}">
```

Achieves the following view [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `toString()` method in `ArticleTag` class and set to return the needed value (`tagName`)

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getTagName();
}
```

Then, setting the list as an object and passing to `toString()` as value, this will return an array, then the square brackets can be removed by using `substring()`.

```
<input class="form-control" id="category"
                    th:object="${article.articleTags}" 
                    th:value="*{toString().substring(1, toString().length()-1)}"/>
```

> End result

[image: end result]